# setTimeOut issues in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Why doesn't the following work in Firefox (v16)?

```
var t = setTimeout(foo(), 1000);
```

The error I get in the console is: "useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)". Wrapping it in quotes doesn't seem to do much, except making it render as a string (unsurprisingly).

It does however work fine when I wrap it in an anonymous function like so:

```
var t =
    setTimeout(function(){
       foo();
     }, 1000);
```

But why is it necessary? Why doesn't it explode in Webkit or Opera? Stroke of luck?

Comment: Try this `var t=setTimeout(foo, 1000)` also you have to define foo(); first ofc.

Comment: `var t = setTimeout(foo, 1000)` better.  String function names use eval.

Comment: Simply because you are not supposed to run the function then put the output into `setTimeout`. You are supposed to put the 'reference' of the function.

Comment: @Nix your code "explodes" in all browsers.  The other ones just aren't telling you about it....

Comment: @BorisZbarsky But the function (`foo()`) still executes. That's the weird thing. Is SpiderMonkey simply more strict, or could it be due to some weird scoping situation in my application?

Comment: @Nix The function should be executing in all browsers, since it's being called.  It's just executing before setTimeout is even called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a method to `setTimeout()`, it will be executed in global scope.  `this` will point to `window` at execution time. Read more [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

If `foo` is not global, it won't be found, ergo `ReferenceError`.

```
var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout, __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
// just backed up the defaults. Now basically creating timeout and setInterval
//functions that take scope as a parameter,
//so you can use them in whichever invocation context you want.

window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};

window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};
```

Comment: Aha, now I understand why it doesn't work, but I still don't understand why it then works fine when I wrap it in an anonymous function. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @alex23 All browsers I have tested set the `this` value of a timeout callback to the window setTimeout was called on when invoking the callback.  That includes Chrome.  So I don't see what "Firefox bug" you're talking about.  The code you copy/pasted is only needed if you want to pass additional arguments to the callback and have it work in old IE versions.  But Nix is not trying to pass any additional arguments!

Comment: @alex23 I'm one of the people who downvoted, and I just removed the vote after seeing you added a more detailed explanation. However, there is no Firefox bug here, it's just how JavaScript works. It would be nice if you removed the mention to a non-existing "bug" from your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Its because you are invoking `foo` in your first example.

Its basically the same as doing this:

```
var tempResultOfFoo = foo();
var t = setTimeout(tempResultOfFoo, 1000);
```

Comment: This would be OK if foo returned a function.  Very meta -- a fucntion that returns a function.  But that is not the case.  Daniel is correct with the issue.